# Did Anselm of Canterbury know any Greek philosophy?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Since Anselm seems to be one of the early major medieval philosophers I was wondering if he knew any Greek philosophy.

Comment: This is a history question, not philosophy. https://iep.utm.edu/anselm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His writing *Monologion* indicates he had secondhand acquaintance with Greek Stoic philosophy at least according to reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anselm_of_Canterbury#Monologion):

> The Monologion (Latin: Monologium, "Monologue"), originally entitled A Monologue on the Reason for Faith (Monoloquium de Ratione Fidei) and sometimes also known as An Example of Meditation on the Reason for Faith (Exemplum Meditandi de Ratione Fidei), was written in 1075 and 1076.

> Anselm requested the works be retitled in a letter to Hugh, Archbishop of Lyon, but didn't explain why he chose to use the Greek forms. Logan conjectures it may have derived from Anselm's secondhand acquaintance with Stoic terms used by St Augustine and by Martianus Capella.

Comment: Excellent answer. Do you think there is any stronger evidence to indicate that he knew some Greek philosophy?

Comment: @GEP The same reference mentioned he had been exiled twice and during exile he helped guide the Greek bishops of southern Italy to adopt Roman rites at the Council of Bari. Also it mentions "De Processione Spiritus Sancti Contra Graecos ("On the Procession of the Holy Spirit Against the Greeks"), written in 1102, is a recapitulation of Anselm's treatment of the subject at the Council of Bari." so seems to me he should be quite familiar with Greek theology and philosophy.